# Cross Reference Subfigures in R Markdown

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown, bookdown, subfigure

I have a figure with subfigures in R Markdown. How do I cross-reference these in the text as `Figure 1a`, `Figure 1b` etc?

````
```{r figgy, fig.cap='Caption', echo = FALSE, fig.ncol = 2, out.width = "50%", fig.align = "center", fig.subcap=c('(a)', '(b)', '(c)')}
plot(1:10)
plot(cars, pch = 19)
boxplot(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)
```
````

Code from [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-subfigure.html). I'm using `bookdown::tufte_handout2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `\subref*` command to refer to the subfigures. Usually, the cross-referencing syntax would be `\subref*{<code-chunk-label>:<plot-serial-no>}`. And I have used `subrefformat=simple` so that the reference style looks like `1a` instead of `1(a)`.

````
---
title: Cross-referencing subfigures
output: 
  bookdown::tufte_handout2:
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[subrefformat=simple]{subfig}
---

```{r}
#| label: figgy
#| fig.cap: "Caption"
#| echo: false
#| fig.ncol: 2
#| out.width: "50%"
#| fig.align: "center"
#| fig.subcap: !expr c("A boring scatterplot", "Another scatterplot", "A boxplot")
#| fig.height: 3

plot(1:10)
plot(cars, pch = 19)
boxplot(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)
```

- Figure \subref*{fig:figgy-1} is a scatterplot
- Figure \subref*{fig:figgy-2} is another scatterplot
- Figure \subref*{fig:figgy-3} is a boxplot
````

---

[image: cross referencing to subfigures in bookdown::tufte_handout2]